# JPOS Restful API send and receive data

Tags: java, api, restful-url, jpos

I configure the RESTFul API in JPOS from [jpos-rest.pdf](http://jpos.org/doc/tutorials/jpos-rest.pdf). 
The problem is I couldn't receive data from the client, but I can send data to the client.
In `Echo.java` class by below code I can send data:

```
package org.jpos.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Path("/echo")
public class Echo {
    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response echoGet() {
        Map<String, Object> resp = new HashMap<>();
        resp.put("success", "true");
        resp.put("Name", "Hamid");
        resp.put("Family", "Mohammadi");
        Response.ResponseBuilder rb = Response.ok(resp, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).status(Response.Status.OK);
        return rb.build();
    }
}
```

[image: Data received from jpos]
How can I receive data from the client? There is no request parameter to find what is the request and its data;

Comment: if you are not able to receive client data , how are you able to respond ? The code that you show doesn't take any input, it simply produces a json response without taking any input. Have you coded any other method that takes some input & client provided input is not reaching your server? If that is the case, please share code.

Comment: @SabirKhan this code from jpos pdf from its site.

Comment: I am confused. jpos site describes above method to be called like - `curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json"`  - i.e. there is no input json. So why are you giving it an input json ? method `echoGet()` doesn't take any input.

Comment: I guess, your code is working perfectly fine. What is the issue?

Comment: @SabirKhan I know there is no input. but I want to send data to JPOS RestFul API, then change data and after that, respond to the client. I'm confusing too, Why there is no input and searching for the answer.

Comment: In that case, your method signature will change & you will be required to use `@Consumes` too. Data coming via Path variable will be consumed by - `@PathParam`. Change your method as per the data that your API server is supposed to take in.

Comment: @SabirKhan How can I use `@PathParam`? Have you any sample or link or any resource?

Comment: See [this](https://codedestine.com/jax-rs-consumes-restful-web-services/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Sabir Khan
I changed the code to:

```
    @Path("/echo")
    public class Echo {
        @PUT
        @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
        @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        @Path("/{name}/{family}")
        public Response echoGet(
                @PathParam("name") String name,
                @PathParam("family") String family,
                String Desc
        ) {
            Map<String, Object> resp = new HashMap<>();
            resp.put("success", "true");
            resp.put("Name", name);
            resp.put("Family", family);
            resp.put("Desc", Desc);
            Response.ResponseBuilder rb = Response.ok(resp,
MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).status(Response.Status.OK);
            return rb.build();
        }
    }
```

and send data to RESTFul API like this:
[image: This]